# Как верно высчитать прошедшее время?

Tags: дата, javascript

Сразу пример
http://jsbin.com/uFUSOZOJ/1/edit?js,output

Я хочу вывести точно сколько прошло лет, месяцев и дней с определённой даты, ибо запись "234234 дней" кажется мне чудовищной. Попробовал выводить отдельно года, месяца и дни, но столкнулся с ошибкой в подсчётах.
Метод getTime() выводит точно, но я не знаю, как верно его дату превратить в годы, месяца и дни, чтоб учесть, что в феврале 28 дней (в високосный год 29), что в нечётном месяце 31 день, а в чётном - 30.
Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать подсчёт.

p.s. решение, что в астрономическом месяце (365 + 365 + 365 + 366) / 48 = 30.4375 дней мне не нравится ввиду такой же своей неточности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так, хотя и без проверок

```
function leapyear(y) {
    if (y%400 == 0) return 1;
    if (y%100 == 0) return 0;
    else if(y%4 == 0) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
var months = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
function diff(d2, d1) {
    var y1, m1, d1, y2, m2, d2, o;
    y1 = d1.getFullYear();
    m1 = d1.getMonth();
    d1 = d1.getDate();
    y2 = d2.getFullYear();
    m2 = d2.getMonth();
    d2 = d2.getDate();
    o = new Object();
    if (d2 < d1) {
        o.d = d2 + months[(m2+11)%12] - d1;
        if(leapyear(y2) && m2 == 2) o.d++; // март на дворе
        m2--;
    } else o.d = d2 - d1;
    if (m2 < m1) {
        o.m = m2 + 12 - m1;
        y2--;
    } else o.m =  m2 - m1;
    o.y = y2 - y1;
    return o;
}
```

Надеюсь, даты до Рождества Христова Вас не интересуют.

**UPD**

Добавлена проверка на кратность года 400, как указал [[@Gurylev](/users/16544/gurylev)](/users/16544/gurylev). Но выражение из его комментария гораздо симпатичней.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Даты до Рождества Христова и даты по старому календарю меня не интересуют)))
Правда, у вас на високосный год проверяется лишь текущий. А если високосным был какой-то из тех, что между двумя датами? А если високосных между датами было несколько?
И объясните, пожалуйста, никак не могу логически понять, что значит эта запись? months[(m2+11)%12]; просто ступорюсь на ней))) судя по всему, именно понимания её мне не хватало чтобы самому это написать.

Comment: И ещё не могу понять, почему в библиотеке datejs.com в проверке на високосный год есть ещё 400? (((year % 4 === 0) && (year % 100 !== 0)) || (year % 400 === 0))

Comment: @Gurylev ну про 400-летние високосные я просто забыл, прошу пардону. Что касается високосных "на трассе", так я исходил из того, что с 01.01.1014 до 01.01.2014 ровно 1000 лет (а уж сколько там дней -- вопрос другой). Что же касается `months[(m2+11)%12]` -- так это вычитание единицы (по модулю 12). Результат getMonth -- от 0 до 11, и если вычесть 1 из 0 (январь), должен получиться декабрь (11).

Answer (score 1):

Была нужна реализация такой же задачи, только плюс часы минуты и секунды. Немного переделал скрипт выше. В нём было, если от даты засечения прошло 23 часа и она была вчера (или позавчера, не суть), то показывается всё-равно один день, хотя прошло 0 дней и 23 часа. Вот собственно, что получилось:

```
function leapyear(y) {
    if (y%400 == 0) return 1;
    if (y%100 == 0) return 0;
    else if(y%4 == 0) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
var months = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
function diff(d2, d1) {
    dt1=d1;
    dt2=d2;
    var y1, m1, d1, y2, m2, d2, o;
    y1 = d1.getFullYear();
    m1 = d1.getMonth();
    d1 = d1.getDate();
    y2 = d2.getFullYear();
    m2 = d2.getMonth();
    d2 = d2.getDate();
    hd = dt1.getHours();
    o = new Object();
    o.h = Math.floor(Math.abs(dt1-dt2)/(1000*60*60));
    while (o.h > 24){
      o.h=o.h-24
    }
    o.min = Math.floor(Math.abs(dt1-dt2)/(1000*60));
    while (o.min >= 60){
      o.min=o.min-60
    }
    o.sec = Math.floor(Math.abs(dt1-dt2)/(1000));
    while (o.sec >= 60){
      o.sec=o.sec-60
    }

    if (d2 < d1) {
        o.d = d2 + months[(m2+11)%12] - d1;
        if(leapyear(y2) && m2 == 2) o.d++; // март на дворе
        m2--;
    } else o.d = d2 - d1;
    if (o.d!=0) if (hd>12){o.d=(o.h>24-o.h)?--o.d:o.d;}else {o.d=(o.h<24-o.h)?--o.d:o.d;}
    if (o.h==24){o.h=0;++o.d;}
    if (m2 < m1) {
        o.m = m2 + 12 - m1;
        y2--;
    } else o.m =  m2 - m1;
    o.y = y2 - y1;
    return o;
}
```